# Error while deploying Spring Batch Application - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jettison/mapped/MappedXMLOutputFactory

Tags: spring, batch-file

I am stuck with this error from last few days , while loading the spring batch application,it keep on giving error 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/spring/batch/jobs/config/context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jettison/mapped/MappedXMLOutputFactory

I have added jettison to my pom and here below my pom file looks like
        
            org.codehaus.jettison
            jettison
            1.3.2
        
        
            org.springframework
            spring-webmvc
            ${spring.version}
        
        
            org.springframework
            spring-oxm
            ${spring.version}
        
        
            org.springframework.batch
            spring-batch-test
            ${spring.batch.version}
            
                
                    jettison
                    org.codehaus.jettison

Answer (score 0):

pom.xml should have dependency like :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, do you see jettision-1.3.2.jar in your maven dependecies?
if you are using eclipse, ctr+sft+t : are you able to see this class?